# Restrict Worksheet_Change to a specified range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to record a list of live data in a separate sheet.

Found this code online which works.

How to do I change the range from one cell A1 to a Range A1:D30?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dest As Range
Application.EnableAnimations = False
On Error GoTo line1
If Target.Address <> "$A$1" Then GoTo line1
    Set dest = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    'MsgBox dest.Address
    Target.Copy dest
line1:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without a custom function. VBA already contains all you need.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:D30")) Is Nothing Then

    ' run some code
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: if this resolves your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]